# Has OptaPlanner's SolverConfig changed significantly mid 8.x?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm starting work switching to ConstraintStreams, and part of that updating to latest OptaPlanner (i.e., `8.35.0.Final`, as of writing) from `8.22.1.Final`.

Somewhere along the line, the following config XML has stopped working.  So, I'm wondering, has there been a backwards-incompatible change between these two versions, w.r.t. the config xml?

The deepest I've been able to debug so far is `DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase` where, at line 45, `entityPlacer` returns an `Iterator` which does not `hasNext`.

This CH phase is the last before the LS phase, and I'm only seeing an exception once the LS phase starts which is due to an uninitialized score.

I'll try tomorrow morning to get a minimum reproducer together with the examples but, for now, this is the best I've got.  I figure somebody might see the issue immediately.

```xml
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
        <queuedEntityPlacer>
            <entitySelector id="id">
                <entityClass>com.blah.MyClass</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
                <selectedCountLimit>200</selectedCountLimit>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="id" />
                    <valueSelector variableName="pv1" />
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="id" />
                    <valueSelector variableName="pv2" />
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="id" />
                    <valueSelector variableName="pv3" />
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="id" />
                    <valueSelector variableName="pv4" />
                </changeMoveSelector>
            </cartesianProductMoveSelector>
        </queuedEntityPlacer>
    </constructionHeuristic>
```

Despite this being a minor version increase, this version bump introduced several backwards-incompatible changes, it seems.  So far, they have been minor, but I can't be sure that something in this config has been deprecated.

Comment: FYI there is no `cacheType` on `constructionHeuristic`, that setting doesn't do anything. The solver config doesn't fail on this, because you don't have XSD validation. If you insert the XSD header, you will get full XML validation.

Comment: Thanks!  The company where I work is (reasonably) picky about letting _anything_ pull from _anywhere_, so it's much simpler to avoid the validation altogether.  That said, I I'm going to push to allow it so that I don't miss something like that again.

Comment: Another alternative would be to write the config in Java. The XML format is just a serialized instance of `SolverConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in `SolutionDescriptor::visitEntitiesByEntityClass`.  See [the diff. on the commit with the change that - I think - causes this issue](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/commit/985ccacb9c6011be280de598c7491f3724e322cb#diff-70688ee65f6ab04aec0d9da2bdd09d04e670c6ac05cd6dddbe328899702bec8eL941).

Before the change, `line 945` checked `entityClass.isInstance(entity)` before adding `entity` to `entityList`.  Now, however, `line 951` checks `entityClass.isAssignableFrom(typeParameter)` before calling the `visitor` `Consumer`.

But, my `Solution` class was only specifying the `interface` of the `@PlanningEntity` on the `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty`, like so:

```java
    @Override
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "vrpName")
    public List<IEntity> getEntities() {
        return super.getLinks();
    }
```

Thus `typeParameter` in `visitEntitiesByEntityClass` is the `interface` `IEntity` and `implementation.isAssignableFrom(implInterface) == false`

Per the `isAssignableFrom` JavaDoc:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.

And so the `visitor` `Consumer` is never called, the `ConstructionHeuristic` `SolverJob` is told that there are no moves that it can make, and we we crash out early with an under-initialized score.

All of that said, I'm not really sure what the best fix is or if there's really a bug and I'm not just making a mess of things.  I have a workaround, however:

To get my stuff to work, I just needed to change the `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty` so that it returns the concrete type rather than the interface; e.g.:

```java
    @Override
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "vrpName")
    public List<ImplementationEntity> getEntities() {
        return super.getLinks();
    }
```

And, lastly, to the OptaPlanner Devs if you read this: it's always been unclear to me how inheritance interfaces with OptaPlanner.  Most of it is straight forward, but there has been a decent amount of "guess-and-check."  It would be much appreciate, by more than just me, I'm sure, if the OptaPlanner docs had more on inheritance w.r.t. the entity classes, etc.

Comment: Good analysis! I'll look into it. Wrt. inheritance and docs - I hear you.

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner's version policy is that minor updates *will* bring changes and deprecations, but *will not* actually make breaking changes. And we do, in fact, regularly deprecate APIs - but we do not remove them, so even if you use deprecated stuff, everything should still work.

What you are describing seems like a bug, definitely not intentional. If you provide a minimal reproducer, something that I can run on my machine to demonstrate the issue, I'll look into it.

Comment: I'm having no luck reproducing this with the OptaPlanner examples, so I must be doing something strange.  Thanks, though.  If I can get the examples to do it, I'll definitely update you guys.

Comment: Regarding the backwards incompatibility, I should have said "... in this config has not been broken."  Regardless, there was at least one backwards incompatible change w.r.t. the Bendable score API changes; e.g., `BendableLongScore` no longer extends `AbstractBendableScore`, rather it implements `IBendableScore`.  So places where `AbstractBendableScore` was used no longer accept a `BendableLongScore`.

Comment: Wrt. `AbstractBendableScore` - yes, you are right. Honestly, we never expected anyone to be using `AbstractBendableScore`, since scores are pretty much exclusively used through their final concrete implementation. So this was the only case not covered by the approach we chose. :-(

Comment: No worries!  It's a simple-enough change.  I only used `AbstractBendableScore<?>` because I wanted to be as broad as I could.

FYI, I've figured out the issue, I believe.  I'm in the midst of writing an answer to the question to provide a work around (however unlikely somebody would need it), and an explanation.